# How to CSS <select> so every option's width is as long as its content

Tags: html, css, select

I'm trying to make it so that there is no box behind the options dropdown, and every option, including the selected option at top, has a background as long as its width. This is what I have so far, which doesn't work at all:

```
.dropdownInline{
       border: 0px !important;
       color:  #E17841;
       padding: 0px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      background: #fff;
      background-position: 78px 10px;
      width: 100px;
      text-indent: 0.01px;
      text-overflow: "";
      font-family: aleo;
      font-size: 33px;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0px;
    width: ??? ;
}
```

Comment: You are setting the width property twice.

Comment: whoops. but still, once I remove that all options become as long as the longest option, creating a giant box

Comment: Can you include your HTML, and possibly a jsfiddle?

Comment: This will not be possible through CSS, but a little bit of JS would be cake.

Comment: Here's the JSF: http://jsfiddle.net/z7Esz/

Comment: I don't mind using a little bit of JS either, but all the ways I saw others do was completely re-coding select class which I'd rather not do. Is there an easier way?

Comment: With pure CSS that isn't possible... you'll need an alternative dropdown box (for instance, with jQuery).

Comment: I'm sorry, but its not possible. The border on the dropdown is rendered by the browser.
See previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639638/how-to-remove-border-of-drop-down-list-css

Comment: You could search for custom dropdown plugins that don't use the default browser select element. That would be a starting point for you to achieve what you want.

Comment: damn, CSS has failed me :/. thanks everyone, tho

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve anything similar to this **[FIDDLE?](http://jsfiddle.net/PbTB3/1/)**

If yes you can use `appearance:none`, but It is only supported in chrome,ff and safari.

```
select{
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    background-color:#eee;
    border:none;
}
```