# Using Jquery for "select" and "option"?

Tags: html, jquery, css, html-select

The first to thank everyone for helping me. Sorry for my english is bad :)

**1.** I need jquery, can take the option is selected for display in a `div`.I need to get the value at the site loaded. And if I choose another option it remains unchanged.

Ex, I have :

```
<div class="example">
<select name="filter1" onchange="filtch1(this,'http://example.com/abc/19','0','1');">
<option value="0">Example</option>
<option value="1">Example 1</option>
<option value="2">Example 2</option>
<option value="3" selected>Example 3</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="demo"></div>
```

And Result:

```
<div class="example">
<select name="filter1" onchange="filtch1(this,'http://example.com/abc/19','0','1');">
<option value="0">Example</option>
<option value="1">Example 1</option>
<option value="2">Example 2</option>
<option value="3" selected>Example 3</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="demo">Example 3</div>
```

**2.** And how I can remove the edges of the `option`. I tried using css but can not be !

[image]

Thanks for visit and help me !

Comment: You mean border of the option tobe remove?

Comment: This will help you to remove the edges http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639638/how-to-remove-border-of-drop-down-list-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `change` event of `select[name=filter1]` get the selected option's text and set it to `.demo`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
    <select name="filter1">
        <option value="0">Example</option>
        <option value="1">Example 1</option>
        <option value="2">Example 2</option>
        <option value="3" selected>Example 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="demo">Selected Here</div>

<script>
    $('select[name=filter1]').change(function() {
        $('.demo').html($('option:selected', this).text());
    }).change(); //auto execute on page load
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But my question made a mistake. So when using your code, it occurs continuously load the page. I've edited the question. Wish you help me again?

Comment: What is `filtch1()` function? @LêTùng

Answer (score 2):

Try to bind a change event to your `select` element and inside of that assign the value of it to the target `div`,

```
$(".example select[name=filter1]").change(function(){
  $(this).closest(".example").next(".demo").text($(":selected", this).text());
  //If you want to access the selected value then just use this.value
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/auLoeoq8/)

And for your second problem, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639638/how-to-remove-border-of-drop-down-list-css) may help.

Comment: There are mistakes in my question. I used your code and add ".change ();'"to auto execute on page load auto but it is a continuous loading page. I've revised the hoi.Mong you help me again? Thank you.
https://jsfiddle.net/auLoeoq8/

Answer (score 0):

In an dropdown on change function do this

also add an id to your dropdown

```
$( "#id" ).change(function() {
      // add another id to your result div and then
('#divId').text(this.text());
}
```