# Black Border Issue On Dropdowns in IE And Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

My select / dropdown  elememt gets a black border when it is active.
This happens only in IE and Edge.

Here's my code:-

```
<select >
    <option value="Organization Size">Organization Size</option>
    <option value="< 100">  100</option>
    <option value="100 - 500"> 100 - 500</option>
    <option value="501 - 1000"> 501 - 1000</option>
    <option value="> 1000">  1000</option>
</select>
```

I am unable to find any solutions for this.

*NOTE: I have to use the select element only I cannot replace it with any other kind of dropdown.*

Thank You.

Comment: *Is this work?*  `*,*:active {outline:none;}`

Comment: Just FYI, you should use HTML entities in the value of your select instead of `<` and `>`. `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

Comment: @pedram I tried it, it does not work. Seems like a browser-specific rendering issue to me, which is hard to workaround

Comment: Are you using `Bootstrap` or any library, plugin, etc?

Comment: Read this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14639698/1929665

Comment: @pedram no I am not using any library I am only using jquery

Comment: @RohitGautam Didn't work for me in IE

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to post a working example? This sounds like a styling issue, but I don't see any CSS/styling at all

Comment: just copy and paste this code and run it in ie. you'll see issue

Comment: I haven't added any styling yet, you may directly run the above code in IE and edge