# how to hide border from select option

Tags: html, css

How to hide the border and background from select options?
I have tried `border: none; and outline: none;`
Doesn't work.

Image:
[image]

And this same question: [How to remove border of drop down list : CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639638/how-to-remove-border-of-drop-down-list-css)

Doesn't work for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove border of drop down list : CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639638/how-to-remove-border-of-drop-down-list-css)

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: tried addin !important at last?  border:none !important;. show your option code

Comment: Code is pretty irrelevant here. You're fighting against the browser. Try javascript libraries like jQuery UI, Selectize, Select2, Select3, ...

Comment: I have tried all options and !important, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

From [the flagged duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639638/how-to-remove-border-of-drop-down-list-css)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried tinkering with my select options and upon inspection it looks like a browser concern. Browsers have a default css stylesheet, like user agent stylesheet seen in the image. You can't make changes in the console to these styles. I do believe it is possible to override these stylesheets though depending on your browser. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet/%22here%22) is a post about overriding user agent stylesheets. Hope this helps!

[image]