# How to remove default chrome style for select option?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

How to remove the default outline generated by chrome for the select option list ?
below i have added outline property to none which disable the select element outline.is there any simple way to remove the option tag's outline?

```
select {
  outline: none;
}
```

Look :
 https://jsfiddle.net/thilinasan166/oqfvugbs/1/

Comment: why do you think `outline:none`  it's not a simple way?

Comment: outline: none is the simple way of doing it

Comment: i need to remove the blue outline generated for select list .so setting outline none for select not working .

Comment: do you men on hover on option the blue background?

Comment: yes.that's the issue.

Comment: This is the thing I try every time and it works fine for me but why is someone downvoting everything. Everything should be explanatory. I guess this question is cursed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style the outline or whatever you call it, for the options dropdown as it comes from default Operating System.

Check this [How to remove border of drop down list : CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639638/how-to-remove-border-of-drop-down-list-css/14639698#14639698) -- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14639698/8040185)

Despite that create your own custom select dropdowns you can find plenty of them on the web

[INSPIRATION for Custom Select Elements](https://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/index3.html)

Comment: seems like that's the solution. searched for a quick solution without going for a custom drop-down to edit or prevent the browser's default behavior..

Comment: @thilinasan16 that is the only way you can customize and present you select box as you want. CSS sometimes can do miracles but sometimes it stands still even after watching us in trouble. Let us hope for the best in future.