# How to remove default styling of IE/Edge opened select box

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have this select, and whenever I'm running it in IE/Edge, there is a thick black border surrounding the opened list of options.

Opened select in Edge:

[image: thick border]

In Chrome, this does not happen:

[image]

Is there a way to override that thick border in IE/Edge? I'd like to have it have a similar border to the one in Chrome.

```html
<select>
 <option>Apple</option>
 <option>Ball</option>
 <option>Cat</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove border of drop down list : CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639638/how-to-remove-border-of-drop-down-list-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to change styles of the generic dropdown in any browser.

But with Javascript, you can replace the default dropdown form elements and completely change them.

Or you can use a ready-made dropdown plugin like [these](https://www.learningjquery.com/2017/09/20-impressive-jquery-plugins-to-replace-the-html-select-box).

[More info](https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/)

[Reinventing a Drop Down with CSS and jQuery](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/reinventing-a-drop-down-with-css-and-jquery/)